# Can I move Windows 11 from regular SSD to one of the partitions on another PCIE NVME SSD?

Tags: linux, ssd, windows-11

I have dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS system. Windows 11 is on regular SSD. I have Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS on 512 GB PCIE NVME. Recently I changed the 512 GB PCIE NVME to 4 TB 512 GB PCIE NVME(bigger and better). 512 GB PCIE NVME's Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS is cloned to 4 TB 512 GB PCIE NVME. I have around 2 TB remaining on my 4 TB 512 GB PCIE NVME. I want to move Windows 11 from C:(regular SSD) to this 2 TB partition.

How to do that? Is there a way to do this without breaking my dual boot system?
I have AOMEI Partition assistant but not findings way to do this work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just move Windows 11.  There are numerous highly secured files that will break Windows if you move them. This will not work.

You can make a proper backup and then put the backup on the new partition but this may break your dual boot.

It may be just as fast to properly reinstall your setup.

Comment: Can I install Windows 11 again and may be this time to the target partition which is on new PCIE NVME drive?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. No problem to install Windows 11 on an new drive. Licensing remains intact.